# how to get a link in js another site

Tags: javascript, get, element

Welcome.

I would like to do something like that on my side was taken value from the other side ,

on the other side of this value is in the script ( javascript ), and here the question arises ,

whether it can be done , how so, how ?

on this page which wants to pull this link is like this:

```
l='http://vrbx017.cda.pl/lq43d6dc861cbecaef46edec5d9b93449e.mp4?st=babAzs9_p-fXt44Wmqa_Hg&e=1437673793';
    jwplayer("mediaplayer140174").setup(
    {
        width:              620,
        height:             387,
        stretching:'uniform',
            'logo.file':"http://static1.cda.pl/v001/img/player/logo-player-creme.png",
        'logo.position':"top-left",
        'logo.link' : '',
        'logo.hide' : false,
        'logo.over' : 0.7,
        'logo.out' : 0.4,
            autostart: false,
      "dock": "true",
      "controlbar.position": "bottom",
      "controlbar.idlehide": "false",
```

i must get link: l='http://vrbx017.cda.pl/lq43d6dc861cbecaef46edec5d9b93449e.mp4?st=babAzs9_p-fXt44Wmqa_Hg&e=1437673793';

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: you want to extract a link from another website? Javascript is executed by the client. What do you want to do?

Comment: "you want to extract a link from another website?" - yes

Comment: I don't really get it...you are searching for a kind of "hack". I have been trying to do such stuff but this is not that trivial...is your website written in php? java?

Comment: html, php and scripts

Comment: both of the websites? are they hosted by urself? If yes, why do you want to do smth like this? better get the URL by asking your webserver instead of hacking the local websites...